# React - files import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have a question about importing files in React.js (create react app).

For example, I have two components **firstComponent.js** and **secondCmponent.js**

In **both** files I import the same file with CSS styles:
import 'some.css';

1. Does this mean that after building the application I will have code from **some.css x2**?
2. If I call the components side by side (at the same time)

example:

```
<div>
    <FirstComponent />
    <SecondComponent />
</div>
```

In the browser memory, **some.css** will be **x2**?

Comment: I think what happens is that webpack bundles everything smartly into a single file..

Comment: AS simple as that , no need to include the `same css files` twice, once you include it will reflect through out the project.

Answer (score 3):

create-react-app under the hood uses Webpack which is a module bundler that takes all your files and output them in one file so when you use a file for example **.css** file in many places webpack will only include that file only one in your output file > so you don't have to worry . that's also works for other assets like images , fonts , js files

learn more about webpack

[webpack tutorial](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/)

Answer (score 0):

But why do you include the same file twice? Why cant you split your css into three files:

- Main.css (contains standard styling)
- FirstComponent.css (contains specific styling for FirstComponent.js)
- SecondComponent.css (contains specific styling for SecondComponent.js)

and then in your files:

### App.js

```
import './Main.css';
class App extends React.Component {
    render () {
        <div>
            <FirstComponent />
            <SecondComponent />
        </div>
    }
}
```

### FirstComponent

```
import './FirstComponent.css';
class FirstComponent extends React.Component {}
```

### SecondComponent

```
import './SecondComponent.css';
class SecondComponent extends React.Component {}
```

this wont give you the double file import like you experience.

#### Another use by ejecting

> dont use this if you dont know what your'e doing..

You can with the help of webpack plugins, manage your chunks that if a thing gets imported N times, it will be moved into a `commons.js` file, before webpack 4 this was called commonChunksPlugin, now at webpack 4, i dont have this in my head, but i do think this is more or less included by default nowadays (need source).

Answer (score 0):

When I was doing export file I use this  is correct way
Import named exports from the file Mamatha.js:
import { name, age } from "./Mamatha.js";

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).